# Iterativelly Calculate in Separate Array in Loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have to arrays, one for predictions and another for true values.

Predictions:

```
array([[ 0.01365575,  0.01523909],
   [-0.00044139,  0.00269908],
   [ 0.03240077,  0.02496629],
   [ 0.03238605,  0.03045709],
   [ 0.03226778,  0.02878774],
   [ 0.03238199,  0.03221421]])
```

Real values:

```
array([[0.01212121, 0.01529052],
   [0.        , 0.0030581 ],
   [0.01818182, 0.01559633],
   [0.00757576, 0.007263  ],
   [0.00757576, 0.00382263],
   [0.00757576, 0.01070336]])
```

I am trying to calculate the std of the mae and rmse with the formula:

```
std_error = (1/n * sum(error_i- mean_error)^2)^1/2
```

So far I am trying to create an array with the mae and rmse values incrementally but with no success. I am implementing this:

```
for x in range(len(preds)):
    mae_std = (preds[:,0] - trues[['t1']])/x

for x in range(len(preds)):
    rmse_std = (((trues[['t2']] - preds[:,1])**2)/x)**1/2
```

This way just takes forever and never really ends not sure why.
I expected the results to be an array with the incremental values of the error and then I could try to use them on the `std_error` formula.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I describe faster?

Comment: you can index the arrays directly and compute the same? something like ```np.mean((preds[:,1] - trues[:,1])**2)``` (just an e.g) or you can use scikit learn metric submodule as well. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 2 arrays are modelizing (x,y) coordinates, you can compute the mse / mae as follows:

```py
# compute MSE
mse = np.square(preds - real)
mse = np.sum(mse, axis = 1) / mse.shape[1]

# compute MAE
mae = np.sum(np.abs(preds - real), axis = 1) / mse.shape[1]
```

You can adapt your specific formula to match these...

Comment: This return  a number. Shouldn't it return an array of the error values for each sample? Because I then want to put them in `error_i` on the `std_error` formula.

Comment: if your initial pred & real arrays are of size (n, 2) then this returns an array of size (n, 1)